# proof that two curves are not homotopic

Tags: homotopy-theory, differential-forms, line-integrals

> Let $$\omega=\frac{x\text{d}y-y\text{d}x}{x^2+y^2}$$ $$c_0,c_1: [0,1]\to\mathbb R^2$$ $$c_0(t)=\Big(\cos(\pi t),\sin(\pi t)\Big), \ \ c_1(t)=\Big(\cos\big((1+t)\pi\big),\sin\big((1+t)\pi\big)\Big)$$

I am trying to prove that $c_0$ and $-c_1$ are **not** homotopic using the following theorem:

> If $c_0,c_1$ are homotopic and $\omega$ is a closed $1$-Form, then $\int_{c_0}\omega = \int_{c_1}\omega$.

So let's assume we already know that $\omega$ is a closed $1$-Form.

Calculation of $\int_{c_0}\omega$:

\begin{align*}
c_0^*\omega&=c_0^*(\frac{x\text{d}y-y\text{d}x}{x^2+y^2})) \\
&=c_0^*(x\ \text{d}y-y\ \text{d}x) \\ 
&=c_0^*(x\ \text{d}y)-c_0^*(y\ \text{d}x) \\
&=\cos(\pi t)\ \text{d}(\sin(\pi t))-\sin(\pi t)\ \text{d}(\cos(\pi t)) \\
&=\pi\cos^2(\pi t)\ \text{d}t+\pi \sin^2(\pi t)\ \text{d}t \\
&=\pi\ \text{d}t \end{align*}
$\implies \int_{c_0}\omega =\int_0^1\pi\ \text{d}t=\pi$

Calculation of $\int_{c_1'}\omega$ (with $c_1'=-c_1)$:
\begin{align*}
c_1'^*\omega&=c_1'^*(\frac{x\text{d}y-y\text{d}x}{x^2+y^2})) \\
&=c_1'^*(x\ \text{d}y-y\ \text{d}x) \\ 
&=c_1'^*(x\ \text{d}y)-c_0^*(y\ \text{d}x) \\
&=-\cos((1+t)\pi)\ \text{d}(-\sin((1+t)\pi))+\sin((1+t)\pi)\ \text{d}(-\cos((1+t)\pi)) \\
&=\pi\cos^2((1+t)\pi)\ \text{d}t+\pi \sin^2((1+t)\pi)\ \text{d}t \\
&=\pi\ \text{d}t \end{align*}
$\implies \int_{c_1'}\omega =\int_0^1\pi\ \text{d}t=\pi$

what makes no sense since I am to prove that $c_0$ and $-c_1=c_1'$ are **not** homotopic. Does anyone see the mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that for any $\theta\in\Bbb R$, $$\cos(\theta +\pi)=-\cos \theta\qquad\text{and}\qquad\sin(\theta +\pi)=-\sin \theta$$
Therefore $c_0=-c_1$.

---

Note also that it should be $\Bbb R^2\setminus\{0\}$ instead of $\Bbb R^2$, for not only $\omega$ is only defined on $\Bbb R^2\setminus\{0\}$, but also any two paths with common endpoints are homotopic in $\Bbb R^2$.

Comment: Thank you! Well, that makes sense. So above all, my approach was wrong. Is there any other way to see though that $c_0$ and $-c_1$ are not homotopic using $\omega$?

Comment: @newbie they are **equal**, therefore homotopic.